# Conditional formatting Error 5, Syntax error and requests use of "="

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007, conditional-formatting, vba

I've been battling this all day and can't figure out why it's happening.

Whenever I add a new conditional format using VBA (and since via Excel's GUI) it won't let me write a formula for highlighting a row based on text in the first cell of that row. No to make this more confusing I have almost identical code later in the sub that does the same thing (with different text) but Excel doesn't give me an error for it.

The below gives me a Run-time Error "5" Invalid Procedure or Argument

```
Range("A10", Range("A10").Offset(ItemsCount - 1, CLPCount + 2)).Select
Selection.FormatConditions.Delete
Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=IF($A10=""Duplication"",TRUE,FALSE)"
Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
Selection.FormatConditions(1).Font.ColorIndex = 2
Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
```

and the says I should by using an "=" with it and when I try to run the code it tells me there is a Syntax issue.

```
   Range("A10", Range("A10").Offset(ItemsCount - 1, CLPCount + 2)).Select
   Selection.FormatConditions.Delete
   Selection.FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=IF($A10=""Duplication"",TRUE,FALSE)")
   Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
   Selection.FormatConditions(1).Font.ColorIndex = 2
   Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
```

Then if I remove from the formula the $ for absolute referencing the column, it passes without issue but doesn't provide the required function. Same thing if I put " around the cell reference.

===========================================================================

**Many thanks to those that have helped.**
We were all right except me, I was wrong and right.... it was how I was running Excel. Excel was running in R1C1 Formula mode, so the problem was with the cell referencing style used in the formula for the conditional formatting when using Excel in this mode.

Answer (score 0):

Change the formula line to:

```
Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=$A10=""Duplication"""
```

I suspect that for whatever reason, the formula string is invalid based on your regional settings - eg you should be using semicolons rather than commas.

Comment: I was just about to write an answer on that.

It lets it pass but the formula won't highlight the row.

Comment: It works perfectly here. Are you sure the cells in A don't have leading or trailing spaces for example?

Comment: They do not have anything but "Ok" or "Duplication", as it's a formula that chooses the text and then the routine goes on to turned the output of the formula into static text.

Comment: All I can say is it works for me, as I would expect, and I can't see any reason for it to fail. Is the data validation in place on the sheet after the code runs?

Comment: I'm there with you Rory, I've written this type of code a load of times over the last year and never hit this kind of trouble before.

I've just closed the file, opened it, tried the code you've given and it's giving the invalid procedure call error again.

Comment: Can you manually apply the conditional formatting you want  while rerocrding a macro, just to check the code?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% what the issue at hand is. I rewrote your code as:

```
Sub conditionalFormatting()
Range("A10", Range("A10").Offset(0, 10)).Select
With Selection.FormatConditions
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=IF($A10=" & Chr(34) & "Duplication" & Chr(34) & ",TRUE,FALSE)"
End With
With Selection.FormatConditions(1)
    .Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    .Font.ColorIndex = 2
    .StopIfTrue = False
End With
End Sub
```

(Changed the offsets to hardcoded values) and it seems to do what the program is supposed to do (mark an area red if $A10 is "Duplication"?). Could you further elaborate?

Comment: I'm not sure I can.

The whole routine does a series of checks on 2 reports. In this case I can't just check for duplicates and presume an action, so I have to highlight and stop for user input. Column A declares if the row is OK or a Duplication. So the conditional formatting uses that to know if the row should be formatted red with white text.

As the range is different whenever the routine is run I can't hard code the area it's adding the conditions to.

Comment: Just tried forcing the Offset to hardcoded values and I'm not getting anything different.

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the edit to the original question.

The issues stems from the referencing style chosen in Excel's options. When using the R1C1 reference style it won't allow you to use an A1 reference style in the formula of conditional formatting.